# How to change background color of buttons on click on any of them?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have 3 buttons. I created a style that I use for all of three of the buttons to show MouseOver and Pressed states. I need to have logic to indicate which button was selected / clicked. If the button is clicked then the background color should stay/be as for pressed state and other two buttons should be reset to background color to be as a normal state. Below is the code I have. I am wondering if it is possible to achieve all in XAML or how to do it in code behind? Thank you I advance.

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
x:Class="test3.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">

<Window.Resources>  
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="#FFFFE640">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFC8B432"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFBCAA31"/>
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Margin="0,0,0,4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseOneEnter">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="button_One">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFDAC326"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseOneLeave">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="button_One">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FFFFE640"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="button_Two">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF85781C"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMoseOneClick">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="button_One">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="#FFDAC326"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Button x:Name="button_One" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="90" Height="90"  Content="One" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" Cursor="Hand" Margin="0,0,0,4" />
        <Button x:Name="button_Two" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="90" Height="90" Content="Two" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" Cursor="Hand" Margin="0,0,0,4" />
        <Button x:Name="button_Three" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="90" Height="90" Content="Two" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}" Cursor="Hand" Margin="0,0,0,4" />
    </StackPanel>   
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're actually after radio button functionality.

http://www.wpftutorial.net/RadioButton.html

Give each radio button the same GroupName and you'll get the functionality you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could change it to use the "IsFocused" propert, instead of "IsPressed"

Answer (score 0):

Toggle buttons? Create a Toggle Button user control that consists of two buttons. One starts out hidden. When you click the visible one, hide it and show the hidden one. Then you can also hide/show the other buttons in an OnClick event.

Comment: I cannot use toggle buttons in my case. Is that possible to control background color values of each button on one button click?