# How to Simulate Button pressed visual in Forms?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm new to WPF and have a question among behavior in forms.

I added a key down event to catch a pressed return key.

Now the Problem, there is no visual feedback. Is it possible to let the button look like it got pressed by the mouse?

It should look like i pressed the button via mouse, but instead after pressing return.

Comment: what type of button is it?

Comment: A normal Button from Toolbox --> System.Windows.Controls.Button

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355355/how-to-change-background-color-of-buttons-on-click-on-any-of-them

Comment: How can I simulate such a Toggle/pressed in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand, you want to simulate the visual effect of a button click, so, to achieve this, you have to change the `IsPressed` property of the button, but is read-only, then, `System.Reflection` is useful:

on `KeyDown` event:

```
typeof(Button).GetMethod("set_IsPressed", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(btnSimulate, new object[] { true });
```

and `KeyUp`:

```
typeof(Button).GetMethod("set_IsPressed", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(btnSimulate, new object[] { false });
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the solution will go by changing the `KeyPressed` event for the button.

See this code example:

`At first, create a button:`

`<ButtonContent="ButtonPressed" Name="buttonPressed" />`

Then you should add `Resources` to your main.xaml that will tell the button how it will look (like CSS in Web Pages).

```
<Window.Resources>
 <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GlowFX}" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="35" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GlowFXPressed}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

With the `Background` property I'm changing the default Background for the button. The `Trigger` launches when you are over your button, and, as you can see, it changes again the background, with these two styles **NOTE: paste them before the Button style:**

```
<RadialGradientBrush x:Key="GlowFX" GradientOrigin=".5,1" Center=".5,1">
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#990000FF"></GradientStop>
        <GradientStop Offset=".3" Color="#660000DD"></GradientStop>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#33000000"></GradientStop>
    </RadialGradientBrush>
    <RadialGradientBrush x:Key="GlowFXPressed" GradientOrigin=".5,1" Center=".5,1">
        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#990000FF"></GradientStop>
        <GradientStop Offset=".3" Color="#880000DD"></GradientStop>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#33000000"></GradientStop>
    </RadialGradientBrush>
```

This works with the event `IsMoseOver`, but I think it would be the same for keypressed. Only look a little bit ;)

As Rachel says, you should rewrite the full template, and tell the Press event what to do with styles.